# visual basic Computer trouble shooting program

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1    
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Me.TextBox1.Text = "Y" Then
            Me.Label3.Text = "contact tech support"
        ElseIf Me.TextBox2.Text = "Y" Then
            Label3.Text = "contact tech support"
        End If
        If Me.TextBox1.Text = "N" Then
            Me.Label3.Text = "bring computer to repair shop"
        ElseIf Me.TextBox2.Text = "N" Then
            Me.Label3.Text = "bring computer to repair shop"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I am having trouble on my codes here 
if textbox1 and textbox2 is Y it should answer "contact tech support"
if textbox1 and textbox2 is N it should answer "bring computer to repair shop 
but what should i do so that textbox1 and textbox2 has different variables and have different passage 
like textbox1 is Y and textbox2 is N and it should be like "check drive contacts"
need help here thanks

Comment: A `Select Case`, switching cases like `"YY"`, `"NN"`, `"YN"`, `"NY"`? A `Dictionary(Of String, String)`, where the Keys (like `"YY"`) match the correct answer?

Comment: This question and its eventual answer are unlikely to be useful to anybody else. You are using SO like a help forum and it's not designed for that - its a question and answer site. The problem you are having is that you don't know how to express the logic you want in an if..elseif..then statement. IMO, this isn't a good place to get an answer for that. That said the solution to your problem is you need to use the logical And keyword If x = blah And Y = blah then something elseif ...etc. etc.

Comment: @schmidlop The question is fine.  User is new to programming.  They posted the code they are using.  They are looking for help.

Comment: Also, consider using a radio button or checkbox if you want a "y"/"N" answer - this makes it easier to set up Boolean logic.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 possible outcomes for 2 boolean values in text box 1 & 2:

- TextBox1.Text:  Y, TextBox2.Text:  Y
- TextBox1.Text:  Y, TextBox2.Text:  N
- TextBox1.Text:  N, TextBox2.Text:  Y
- TextBox1.Text:  N, TextBox2.Text:  N

Structure your code similarly so you know you've covered all the cases

```
If Me.TextBox1.Text = "Y" And Me.TextBox2.Text = "Y" Then
    Me.Label3.Text = "Something"
ElseIf Me.TextBox1.Text = "Y" And Me.TextBox2.Text = "N" Then
    Me.Label3.Text = "Something Else"
ElseIf Me.TextBox1.Text = "N" And Me.TextBox2.Text = "Y" Then
    Me.Label3.Text = "Another Thing"
Else
    Me.Label3.Text = "Final Thing"
End If
```

If at any point you know there are no more combinations of interest, then use the `Else` statement earlier. For example, if it was the case that whenever TextBox2 is N then we always want to display the text "Final Thing". Then expression has once less branch, like so:

```
If Me.TextBox1.Text = "Y" And Me.TextBox2.Text = "Y" Then
    Me.Label3.Text = "Something"
ElseIf Me.TextBox1.Text = "Y" And Me.TextBox2.Text = "N" Then
    Me.Label3.Text = "Something Else"
Else
    Me.Label3.Text = "Final Thing"
End If
```